# mockgen not creating mocks

Tags: go, mocking

Here's my folder structure:

```
demo/
|-- go.mod
|-- main.go
|-- interfaces/
|   |-- interfaces.go
|-- mocks/
```

This is my go.mod file

```
go 1.20

require (
    github.com/golang/mock v1.6.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/mod v0.4.2 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210510120138-977fb7262007 // indirect
    golang.org/x/tools v0.1.1 // indirect
    golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20200804184101-5ec99f83aff1 // indirect
)
```

Here's my interfaces.go

```
package interfaces

type MyInterface interface {
    DoSomething() error
    GetValue() int
}
```

When i tried to run the mockgen command ,it is not creating the mocks and instead giving me this help description:
mockgen has two modes of operation: source and reflect.Source mode generates mock interfaces from a source file. It is enabled by using the -source flag. Other flags that may be useful in this mode are -imports and -aux_files.

https://manpages.org/mockgen

I ran the following command: **mockgen -destination=mocks/mock_myinterface.go -package=mocks demo/interfaces MyInterface**

How to use the mockgen command correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the maintained fork from Uber instead (as Google abandoned golang/mock): https://github.com/uber-go/mock

If you just run the `mockgen` command you get the command options. Something that should work for you is something like this:

```
mockgen -source interfaces/interfaces.go -destination mocks/mocks.go
```